# How to add prefix and suffix to selected text

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to make a simple WYSIWYG editor.

When a text is selected/highted from the `<textarea>`, and the button with the *btn* id is clicked, JS will add a prefix `<a href=''>` and a suffix `</a>`.

This is what I've come up. But it doesn't work on jsfiddle.

```
    //JS
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function markupEd() {
            var textArea = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
            var i = 0;
            var textArray = val.value.split("\n");

            for (i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
                textArray[i] = "<a href=''>" + textArray[i] + "</a>";
            }
            val.value = textArray.join("\n");
        }
    </script>


    <input type="button" id="btn" value=" <a> " onclick="markupEd();">
    <textarea id="textInput"></textarea>
```

Comment: it wont ... you will get an error .... where does `val` come from  ?? `val.value.split("\n");`

Comment: @ManseUK I got it from the code I made when adding a prefix value and a suffix value from two different `input` tags. Then it will be displayed on a `textarea` tag with the text from another `textarea`.

Comment: @ManseUK But this time, my problem is how the button would recognize the selected text, as well as add the default prefix and suffix that I want, when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS function looks good..I dont think you need to pass any value to your function

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function markupEd() { 
            var textArea = document.getElementById('textInput').value; 
            var i = 0; 
            var textArray = textarea.split("\n"); 

            for (i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) { 
                textArray[i] = "<a href=''>" + textArray[i] + "</a>"; 
            } 
            document.getElementById('textInput').value = textArray.join("\n"); 
        } 
   </script>     

    <input type="button" id="btn" value=" <a> " onclick="markupEd();"> 
    <textarea id="textInput"></textarea>
```

Comment: yes, sir. thanks for pointing that out. just edited the code as you said. just improved my question, too.